# Add divs to sections without breaking the scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making this website [here](http://clashnow.maxfet.net:9010/), and I'm using `sections` in order to have that smooth **scrolling effect** you see there.

I now need a `navigation bar`, but **if** I put it **before** the `sections` (so out of them) it happens that everytime I scroll there's a short crop**strong text** of the section before in the new section.

Instead **if** I put it **inside**, the `height` of it **won't** display **correctly**.

So my question is: **how can I insert that nav bar without breaking up the scrolling efect so it will display the full section each time?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding "position:fixed" to the navigation bar and add padding from top to the sections equal to the height of the navigation bar.

After inspecting you website :This is what you need to do

```
#cssmenu {
    background: #8EBEBC;
    width: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 9;
}
#fullpage{ 
    padding-top:58px;
}
```

and you are good to go.

Thanks

Comment: If I put position: fixed the nav disappears, shouldn't be a z-index issue as the other element is a background, right?

Comment: with the position fixed you also need to add top:0 and if required also add left:0 and right:0 as well.

Comment: Take a look to the website now, I used position: fixed top, left,right : 0

Comment: You have to remove position fixed from ul and add it to the container.
#cssmenu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 9;
}

and also add this to the fullpage div
#fullpage{
padding-top:58px;
}

Comment: Awesome man, works great :) One last question, how am I supposed to add a logo in the nav bar? I tried but the image made the nav bar taller

Comment: Updated the website so you can see what I mean

Comment: If you do not want the navbar to grow taller then use smaller image.With the current image you can set height:35px and padding-top:12px to make it vertically center.Please apply these properties to img tag not the li.

Comment: May I ask you how you counted these attributes? :)

Comment: However it's still a bit too higher than normal, what should be the right height? I mean the right resolution to set the image to in order to fit properly in the nav bar without altering the natural height of it?